# How do you handle current user and a list of users?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm having a situation (pretty standard for everybody i guess), where i have to do two things :

1. If a user asks for /user path, i have to present his/her personal information.
2. If a user asks for /user/:id path, i have to present information about that particular user, or the current user information if :id matches the current_user id.

There are definitely many ways to do that, but what is the best approach ? Should i have 2 different routes like /show/:id and /show_current, handled by different actions, or just have a /show/:id and do the handling in that action ?

Bear in mind that if this is the current view, i need to render a different more detailed view than the one about another view. I think the latter is probably the better way,but what do you think ?

Comment: Is the /user path (the first one) more like an edit as opposed to a show?

Comment: Not really an edit, more of a view page, but a more detailed version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the current user is, say, 42 then `/user/42` and `/user` would display the same information but `/user/23` would display a stripped down public version of 23's data. So, the handler for `/user/:id` will have to know about the special case of `:id` being the current user; the handler for `/user` will also have to know about this special case as that's all it does.

If you use two routes then you'll either be duplicating code, wrapping the real code in an extra layer, or some other bit of busy work. I'd just send them both to the same controller method and that could start with something like this:

```
user = params['id'] ? User.find(params['id']) : current_user
```

And then later on you handle the special case of the requested user being the current user in just one place with something simple:

```
if(user == current_user)
    # show the full blob of information
else
    # show just the limited public information
end
```

You could, of course, slice it up into a bunch of little methods, such as `show_current_user_info` and `show_other_user_info`, inside the controller. The handler for `/user` could just be a call to `show_current_user_info`; the `/user/:id` handler could call `show_current_user_info` or `show_other_user_info` depending on what `:id` is. This approach smells like pointless layering to me.

Comment: yeah, this seems like the best way to do it for me as well. Single route. Thanx.

Answer (score 1):

In RESTful routing, you've described `users_path` and `user_path(some_id)`. These map to `User#index` and `User#show`. The `index` method is normally a list of users, but if you are wanting `index` to show the `current_user` personal information, you can certainly do that. If you also need a list method, just add it to your controller and create a route to it.

Comment: What do you think is better though. A single route to handle both cases(current and other user), or two separate routes ?

Comment: If your view has to be different for the "current user," then it makes sense to have two actions that each renders a different, well, view. Something like [https://gist.github.com/fc0fbc198bd840ad1283](https://gist.github.com/fc0fbc198bd840ad1283) makes sense to me.